# Windows phone 8 app transfer

Tags: windows-phone-8

I've created an app for windows phone 8.Now I want to demonstrate it to my client without giving my code. How can I get my app installed on his device if he is in another country.

I appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: this more belongs on another site, im not sure which exactly but superuser.com seems like a good option. It belongs somewhere else because it isn't actually a programming question, it is a question about how to do something with a device

Comment: thanks, i will ask it there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build the **XAP package** and send it to him. He can then install it on his device using the development tools. Be aware however, that the development XAP file produced by Visual Studio is **just a "zip" file**, and can be extracted to reveal your XAML code and DLLs, that can be then read by Reflector for example.

A **better and safer way** for you would be to publish the app to Windows Phone Store as a **private beta** and give your client access to it. This way your code is safer, because it is obfuscated in Store and your client will be able to test it as far as he wants without being able to look at you code.